# Rails new initialized object create an empty record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two model called `TodoList` and `TodoItem`. In the TodoItem index page, i'm showing new form and list of todo items. Everything works perfect But it generate an empty record while in browser.

```
class TodoItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :todo_list
end
```

```
class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todo_items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

controllers have:

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    @todo_items = @todo_list.todo_items
    @new_todo = @todo_list.todo_items.new
  end

  def create
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(params.require(:todo_item).permit(:description, :complete_at))
    if @todo_item.save
      redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_path(@todo_list)
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div>
  
  <div>
    <% form_with(model: [@todo_list, @todo_item], local: true) do |f| %>
      <% f.text_field :description %>
      <% f.submit %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
    <ul>
    <% @todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
      <li><%= todo_item.description %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you consider  what happens if `save` returns false?

Comment: No. As i'm learning something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  # use callbacks instead of repeating yourself
  before_action :set_todolist, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  def index
    @todo_items = @todo_list.todo_items
    @todo_item = TodoItem.new
  end

  def create
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(todo_list_params)
    if @todo_item.save
      redirect_to [@todo_list, :todo_items]
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_todolist
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
  end

  # use a private method for your params whitelist for readibility
  # it also lets you reuse it for the update action
  def todo_list_params
    params.require(:todo_item)
          .permit(:description, :complete_at)
  end
end
```

You where setting a different instance variable (`@new_todo`) in you index action. The polymorphic route helpers that look up the route helpers from `[@todo_list, @todo_item]` call compact on the array. So if `@todo_item` is nil its going to call `todo_lists_path` instead - ooops!

You alway also need to consider how you are going to respond to invalid data. Usually in Rails this means rendering the new view. If you are rendering the form in another view such as the index view it can get kind of tricky to re-render the same view as you have to set up all the same data as that action which leads to duplication.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `@new_todo` has been added to `@todo_items` somehow in `index` action:

```rb
def index
  @todo_items = @todo_list.todo_items
  @new_todo = @todo_list.todo_items.new
  # The above line has a side effect: @todo_items = @todo_items + [@new_todo]
end
```

I'm not sure it's a bug or feature from Rails (I use Rails 6.1.1).

For a quick fix, you can change `@todo_list.todo_items.new` to `TodoItem.new`.

Comment: I use Rails 6.1.1 too. I wouldn't consider it as a feature since it add an '<li>' tag in views.

Comment: This is not quite true - using the shovel operator `<<` would save @new_todo. And its definitely the intended behovior of new.  https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-new

Comment: It works already but it should not create an empty object and show it in views.

Comment: @max Yeah, it should be `@todo_items = @todo_items + [@new_todo]` for explaination.